# goto function in batch file not working after parenthesis if statement

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So im trying to make it so that if the player presses a random key than it will just go back to the last label. It works if you press a key and then press enter but if you press just enter than it closes. Pls help:

```
    @echo off
title dragon game
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:main
cls
color 07
echo Welcome to the Dragon's Journey Game
echo ------------------------------------
echo Please select an option:
echo.
echo 1)New Game
echo 2)Load
echo 3)About This Game
echo 4)Exit
set /p c=)                

if "%c%" == "1" goto new
if "%c%" == "2" goto load
if "%c%" == "3" goto about
if "%c%" == "4" goto exit
goto main

:about
cls
color 07
echo  ##############################################
echo ##This game was made purely for fun. So if you##
echo ##complain about it being too bad, well try to##
echo ##make a better one, because I don't have time##
echo ##to deal with you right now. Sayonara!  -Greg##
echo  ##############################################
pause
goto main

:exit
echo Are you sure you want to exit? (Y/N)
echo -----------------------------------
echo set /p c=)

if "%c%" == "y" exit
if "%c%" == "n" goto main
goto exit

:new
set strength=50
set intelligence=50
set infamy=50
set incognito=50
set stubbornness=50
set patience=50
set maneuverability=50
set flames=50
set brutality=50
set patience=50
set cap=100
set maturity=youth
set lair=none
goto name

:name
cls
color 07
echo Before you begin, please enter your name:
echo -----------------------------------------
set /p name=
goto surename

:surename
cls
color 07
echo Are you ok with the name, %name%? (Y/N)
echo ---------------------------------------
set /p c=)

if "%c%" == "y" goto pre
if "%c%" == "n" goto name
goto surename

:pre
cls
color 07
echo Prepare to enter a fantastical world full of werms and serpents!
echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
echo Are you sure you are prepared, %name%? (Y/N)
echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
set /p c=)

if "%c%" == "y" goto backstory
if "%c%" == "n" goto name
goto pre

:backstory
cls
color 80
echo As a child, you had several siblings, all of whom 
echo you competed with for your mother's favor.
echo.
echo Did you pursue a life of hunting, or a more 
echo subtle life of reading and gaining knowledge.
echo --------------------------------------------------
echo 1)Hunting
echo 2)Reading
echo 3)I did my fair share of both
set /p c=)

if "%c%" == "1" (
set strength=75
set intelligence=25
goto youth
)
if "%c%" == "2" (
set strength=25
set intelligence=75
goto youth
)
if "%c%" == "3" goto youth
goto backstory

:youth
cls
echo Good, good.
echo.
echo You are now a youth dragon who must fend for 
echo himself, after your mother died during a raid.
echo.
echo You are resting in a cavern for the time being.
echo However, you are cramped with little space for
echo comfort. You venture out to seek a new lair.
echo.
echo Which direction do you go?
echo -----------------------------------------------
echo 1)North
echo 2)South
echo 3)East
echo 4)West
set /p c=)

if "%c%" == "1" (
set lair=north1
goto northlair1
)
if "%c%" == "2" (
set lair=south1
goto southlair1
)
if "%c%" == "3" (
set lair=east1
goto eastlair1
)
if "%c%" == "4" (
set lair=west1
goto westlair1
)
goto youth
```

The problem is in the last label

Comment: Hopefully someone can answer your question, but I'd like to point out that writing adventure games in batch is an exercise in masochism.  You might be interested in [smash](http://www.rinkworks.com/smash/) or [another text adventure game engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Text_adventure_game_engines).

Comment: Instead of using `set /p` you should use the `choice` command

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p c=)
```

Has a closing without opening brace.

```
Choice /c 1234 /n 
if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 echo 1 chosen
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that `set /p var=prompt` will set `var` to *nothing* if you simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but this is not so. It will leave `var` unchanged, so it will retain the last entry made and hence exit to *lair1 (which is not defined)

To ensure the behaviour you are expecting, use

```
set "c="
set /p c=)
```

Note that this characteristic can be used to set a default

```
set c=6
set /p c=)
```

will leave `c` as `6` if <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone is used.

Try reading up on the `call` command.

```
call :getresponse
```

would execute a subroutine ":getresponse" which might be

```
:getresponse
set "c=%~1"
set /p C=)
goto :eof
```

to provide your expected behaviour, and

```
call :getresponse defaultvalue
```

would get the response but allow you to set a default for <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone.